# jQuery "width: toggle" in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate, width

Here is my simple problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bergkamp/FBxGX/12/

I want to show always one "red div". It's working IE and Firefox, but in Chrome i can open only once, then when i open again the red div box goes to the bottom of the "grey div". 
I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make the wrappers have `float` property, they are just inline-block, right? (because they have fixed width)

Removing the

```
.befoglalo{
 float:left;
}​
```

gives you what you want, as you can see here: (as tested in Chrome latest, Firefox recent, Safari 5, Opera idk and IE7/9)

http://jsfiddle.net/FBxGX/13/